# Does $\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow a} (f(x)-g(x)) =0$ imply $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same sign if $x$ is sufficiently close to $a$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Does $\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow a} (f(x)-g(x)) =0$ imply $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same sign if $x$ is sufficiently close to $a$?

Could it be that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are different signs, but $|f(x)-g(x)|$ just keeps getting smaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f(x)=x, g(x)=-x$ to obtain a counter example for $a=0$.